# Dutch National Flag

Tags: algorithm, sorting, dutch-national-flag-problem

I understand DNF Problem for 3 Colors. Assume I want to extend the number of colors to 5 (0,1,2,3,4), can I still get O(n) complexity?

So I think we have 5 areas where 2 is the unknown area. But how to implement this? Can I easily extend the algorithm for 3 Colors to 5?

```
void sort012(int a[], int arr_size){
int lo = 0;
int hi = arr_size - 1;
int mid = 0;

while (mid <= hi){
    switch (a[mid]){
    case 0:
        swap(&a[lo++], &a[mid++]);
        break;
    case 1:
        mid++;
        break;
    case 2:
        swap(&a[mid], &a[hi--]);
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely `O(n)`: trivially doable in `O(nk)` as long as the number of colors `k` is constant.

For an algorithm similar to three-way partition ([Dutch National Flag problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem)), I'd suggest a two-pass algorithm. For example, on the first pass, we treat `0` as the left part, all of `1`, `2`, and `3` as the middle part, and `4` as the right part. On the second pass, we skip `0`s and `4`s at the borders, and do a three-way partition of the `1`s, `2`s and `3`s. Note that the result is a stable partition: on each pass, the order of identical elements remains the same.

Comment: The partitioning in Dutch National Flag is not stable.
The relative order of similar elements always change.